# 0xc00007b Error On Starndard Users

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, syntax-error, runtime-error

i got problem win i run my application ( Made With VS 2013 - C# )
Only Work On Administration User

if its Standard user Or The PC/Laptop got a Deep Feeze Software Installed
its Show me this Error

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b). click ok to
>   close the application

i tried to install "all in one runtimes CD"
but its also didnt work

is there any sulotion ?

sorry for my bad english and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

0xc000007b error usually comes from mixing up a 32-bit environment with a 64-bit one. Example, the 32-bit application loads a 64-bit dll causing 0xc000007b error. Try to re-install your application and .NET Framework

Answer (score -2):

**Error 0xc00007b** occurs because the program that you installed and your system belong to different chipset processors.

E.g. your system is 32-bit and the application which you downloaded is built for 64-bit. So first understand what is your system and application's target platform, then use/run the correct binary files.